# Is there a way to run this http response callback in an asynchronous way?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, httpserver

I'm building a basic http server (using only inside lan, to do some things) and for that im using node js. I've started my server and i wrote a basic callback function to respond to http requests. However, i wanted to see what would happen if the function i'm running took some time to conclude (like a db query, for example). So i've wrote this:

```
const http = require("http");
const router = require("../routes/router").router;
const config = require("../config/serverconf.json");

class HttpServer {
    constructor() {
        this.httpServer = http.createServer();
        this.httpServer.on("request", (req,res)=>{return new Promise((resolve)=>{
            setTimeout(()=>{
                res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/plain"});
                res.write("Hello World!");
                res.end();
            },2000);
            console.log("resolved");
            console.log("--------")
            resolve("ok");
        })});
        this.httpServer.listen(config.port, config.host);
    }
}
```

(It was a little more complex, i tried to put it all in the same snippet to better show my problem).

From my understanding, when a request arrives, the callback function creates a new promise, that runs the function in the promise constructor. This function schedules the timeout callback, logs some stuff, then resolves the function. However, it seems that despite the function have already finished, when another request arrives, it waits for the timeout callback function to finish before scheduling the next request's timeout callback. (For example, if i were to get two requests "at the same time" one would take 2 seconds to finish, and the other would take 4). Am i thinking about it the wrong way? If so, how could i achieve something like title's idea. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Testing further, aparently when i write something to the response stream (with ´res.write()´, even a empty string) an THEN schedule the callback with timeout, then it works "as intended" (as i intended it to run, still dont know if i'm doing something wrong here)

Comment: "*it seems that […] when another request arrives, it waits for the timeout callback function to finish before scheduling the next request's timeout callback*" - no, that should not happen. How do you know when the requests arrive? How do you make them?

Comment: @Bergi I dont know if it's the right way to do it, but i have 4 Chrome tabs open, i just f5 them very quickly. I also log when the promise resolves. So when i f5 one tab, it logs "resolved" in no time, just as expected. But if i f5 another tab while the timeout has not returned, it waits for the timeout to return, then it logs another "resolved". I'm wondering if it has something to do with this particular package of node...?

Comment: Hm, it might be chrome throttling these requests (for the exact same URL?)… Try multiple different browsers, or different pages

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently, there was something wrong with my browser (using Google Chrome, but tried on MS Edge too). I changed my code a little bit and tried again. This time the response times were very inconsistent, but it seemed like it was kinda working. Took the advise from @Bergi and tried making the requests with curl and sure enough, it worked just fine (without the chunked encoding). Heres the new code:

HttpServer.js:

```js
const http = require("http");
const router = require("../routes/router").router;
const config = require("../config/serverconf.json");

class HttpServer {
    constructor() {
        this.httpServer = http.createServer();
        this.httpServer.on("request", async (request, response)=>{
            let responseParams = await router.routeCall(request);

            response.writeHead(responseParams.responseCode, responseParams.headers);
            response.write(responseParams.body);
            response.end();
        });
        this.httpServer.listen(config.port, config.host);
    }
}
```

router.js:

```js
class router{

    static routeCall(url){
        switch(url){
            default:
                return new Promise((resolve)=>{
                    setTimeout(()=>{
                        resolve({
                            "responseCode":200,
                            "body":"Message Resolved! Hello! :D",
                            "headers":{"Content-Type":"text/plain"}
                        });
                    }, 2000);
                });
        }
    }
}
```

I would still like to know what is wrong with the first aproach, as i really dont know why it fails (at least on my end). Thanks again @Bergi :D

Comment: Do concurrent requests work when using curl with the original code?

Comment: I was just testing that, and yes it works like a charm. Could be something with the browser, or maybe even with my machine tbh. I really dont know...

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's the browser caching, not make two requests at the same time to the same page. It might even have worked with one tab loading http://localhost/one and the other tab loading http://localhost/two